# When a user has multiple roles, is there a way to pick one role for the remainder of the session in asp.NET Core MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-authorization

I am using Visual Studio 2017, and I have an asp.NET Core MVC project where some users have multiple Roles. I am wondering if there is a way to set just one of these Roles to be the user's only Role for the remainder that user's session.

For example, if the user belongs to two Roles, NormalUser and AdminUser, and they want to use the app as a NormalUser, is there something I can set so that a Role check like `User.IsInRole(nameof(RoleNames.AdminUser))` will return false, but `User.IsInRole(nameof(RoleNames.NormalUser))` will return true?

Does the framework provide any such functionality?

Comment: Roles are equivalent to Windows Groups.  Just as in Windows you can not choose a "session group", you can not choose an "active role" in MVC.  Roles are just a way of applying permissions.  What you are seeking to do is usually accomplished via multiple accounts.

Comment: Identity doesn't have anything like that built in but you could certainly add that.  If you really want it to be session based then you'd either have to add a field to the token and deserialize it or alter the db and save it there.  `UserSessionRole` something like that, and add it to the User model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. If a user is in a role, they are in that role. The main problem here, I think, is that you're trying to use roles for a purpose they are not meant for. If you want an "admin user" to be able to see the site as a "normal user", you could simply add something to the session:

```
Session["ViewAsNormalUser"] = true;
```

Then, you can simply do your checks like:

```
if (!User.IsInRole(nameof(RoleNames.AdminUser)) || Session["ViewAsNormalUser"] as bool? == true)
{
    // do normal user thing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select a role for user for current session you can do one of the following .

1- You can use **Claims** and add this user to Admin Claims for example or Normal Claims. See the below code

```
await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(user, new Claim("RoleValue", "Admin or Normal"));
```

The advantage of this is the role settings will stay with you always and if you want to change the settings you can remove current Claims using **RemoveClaimAsync** method and add a new claims.

2- As [Chris Pratt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/654031/chris-pratt) mentioned you can use session but there are things you need to consider it when you want to use session for example a Sticky session sociability when your web app on web farm.

More can be found on this article 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state#session-state

I hope that help.